# Distributional Virtual Black Box security

Tags: security-definition, obfuscation

Can anyone clearly explain the difference between these two notions of obfuscation security: VBB security and D-VBB Security.

VBB Security: An obfuscated program is no better than just a black box access to the program

D-VBB Security : Let $D = \{D_n\}_{n\in N}$ be a sequence of distributions on F, and O an obfuscator for the F functionality. Then O is said
to be D-DVBB secure if for any adversary A and any sequence of predicates
$P = \{P_n : F_n \rightarrow \{0, 1\}\}$ there exists a PPT Simulator S such that

$$ Pr_{f \leftarrow D_n,A, O}[A(O(f))= P_n(f)] \approx Pr_{f \leftarrow D_n,S}[S^f(1^n) = P_n(f)]$$

Why are we using predicates in this definition?

Comment: For VBB, $S$ has to simulate $A$ for all $f$ in $F$, not only for the functions sampled by $D_n$. As for the predicates, I don't know why they are used here. It seems that we could simply replace $P_n(f)$ by $1$ in both probabilities. Maybe if you link the source where you took that definition from, someone can check it and provide a more precise answer.